# Beamer: Change color/underline but do not hide/shade other section in table of contents

Tags: beamer

I would like the current section to be underlined in `\AtBeginSection` or the same as `\alert{}` but want the other sections to be visible.

So it would look something like:

Before first section:

```
* Section1
  --------
* Section2
```

Before second section:

```
* Section1
* Section2
  --------
```

I can't see the "shaded" style at all that you can use in:

```
 sectionstyle=⟨style for current section⟩/⟨style for other sections⟩
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefined the `beamer` templates for `section in toc` and `section in toc shaded`.  If you have subsections too, you will need to make corresponding new definitions.  In such a template redefinition the command `\inserttocsection` adds the print representation of the section title.  Thus

```
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\underline{\inserttocsection}}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc shaded}{\inserttocsection}
```

prints the current section underlined and the other section as standard (without opaqueness).  You can replace `\underline` here by `\alert` to obtain the other effect.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\underline{\inserttocsection}}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc shaded}{\inserttocsection}

\begin{document}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\section{A section}

\section{Another section}


\end{document}
```